# reading more than 10000 samples in influxdb python

Tags: python, influxdb

Hi I am using python to connect to influxdb to get the data. But it seems the python client query only return 10000 samples of the database. Is there any way to increase the size of the data returned by the python query?

Comment: It sounds like that might be a restriction on the database side, not python. https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/administration/config/#coordinator

Comment: Thanks, do you know if it is possible to change this limit?

Comment: I think the limit in the file you mentioned is 100000 where Python library returns 10000. Also using CLI I can get many more than 10000 records.